# Order of $\,\textrm{vp} \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \otimes \textrm{vp} \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$

Tags: analysis, distribution-theory

I know $\textrm{vp} \left( \dfrac{1}{x} \right)$ is a distribution of order exactly $1$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Therefore $\textrm{vp} \left( \dfrac{1}{x} \right) \otimes \textrm{vp} \left( \dfrac{1}{x} \right) $ is of order at most $2$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$; but is it exactly $2$ ?

I can't find a sequence of functions which would help me prove that it is (nor can I prove that the order is at most 1).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is $\partial_x \partial_y \log |x|\log |y|$ so take $\phi$ supported on a small ball around $0$ and keep $\|\phi\|_\infty,\|\partial_x\phi\|_\infty,\|\partial_y\phi\|_\infty$ small but $\partial_x\partial_y\phi(0)$ large, it will prove that the order is $2$.